# Custom HTTP Header not set when checking using PHP

Tags: php, api, http-headers

I have an API I developed, and I am now trying to send a header with a value called "own_language". However I can't seem to

```
$lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_own-language'];
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$hstring = "";
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    $hstring .= "$header: $value".' ---- ';
}

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $obj = json_decode($postdata, true);
    $method = $_REQUEST["method"];
    if($method == "test"){
        $output = array(
            "head" => $lang,
            "head2" => $hstring
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
```

If i set `$lang` to `$_SERVER['HTTP_own-language']` or `$_SERVER['own-language'];` I always get `null`.

Here is a screenshot of Postman, the API Tester I am using.

[image]

This is what the code I provided outputs, so appearently `own_language` is set but `$lang` is always `null`. Why?

Comment: You probably want the [`apache_request_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) method rather than the `$_SERVER` superglobal, which only contains a very limited set of information taken from headers.

Comment: @Chris Huh? I already use that function and as far as I can see, it isn't possible to get a specific header using this function?

Comment: You don't actually use it to get the header though, you are using `$_SERVER` for that. As you can see from `data2`, your custom header is in there. You just need to do `apache_request_headers()["Own-Language"]`.

Comment: @Chris Neat! Works great, thank you very much.